# Language Country Code Conversion

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to convert language country codes like the ones below into the name of the actual language?

```
en_US
de_DE
en_GB
it_IT
fr_FR
```

I have a dynamic input and would need to convert the language country code to the corresponding name of the language (i.e en_US = English, fr_FR = French).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this code and it works fine i have used the codes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**

```
<?php
    $strLcodes = '<tr><td>af</td><td>Afrikaans </td><td>sq</td><td>Albanian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-sa</td><td>Arabic (Saudi Arabia) </td><td>ar-iq</td><td>Arabic (Iraq) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-eg</td><td>Arabic (Egypt) </td><td>ar-ly</td><td>Arabic (Libya) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-dz</td><td>Arabic (Algeria) </td><td>ar-ma</td><td>Arabic (Morocco) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>ar-tn</td><td>Arabic (Tunisia) </td><td>ar-om</td><td>Arabic (Oman) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-ye</td><td>Arabic (Yemen) </td><td>ar-sy</td><td>Arabic (Syria) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-jo</td><td>Arabic (Jordan) </td><td>ar-lb</td><td>Arabic (Lebanon) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ar-kw</td><td>Arabic (Kuwait) </td><td>ar-ae</td><td>Arabic (U.A.E.) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>ar-bh</td><td>Arabic (Bahrain) </td><td>ar-qa</td><td>Arabic (Qatar) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>eu</td><td>Basque </td><td>bg</td><td>Bulgarian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>be</td><td>Belarusian </td><td>ca</td><td>Catalan </td></tr>
    <tr><td>zh-tw</td><td>Chinese (Taiwan) </td><td>zh-cn</td><td>Chinese (PRC) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>zh-hk</td><td>Chinese (Hong Kong SAR) </td><td>zh-sg</td><td>Chinese (Singapore) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>hr</td><td>Croatian </td><td>cs</td><td>Czech </td></tr>
    <tr><td>da</td><td>Danish </td><td>nl</td><td>Dutch (Standard) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>nl-be</td><td>Dutch (Belgium) </td><td>en</td><td>English </td></tr>

    <tr><td>en-us</td><td>English (United States) </td><td>en-gb</td><td>English (United Kingdom) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>en-au</td><td>English (Australia) </td><td>en-ca</td><td>English (Canada) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>en-nz</td><td>English (New Zealand) </td><td>en-ie</td><td>English (Ireland) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>en-za</td><td>English (South Africa) </td><td>en-jm</td><td>English (Jamaica) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>en</td><td>English (Caribbean) </td><td>en-bz</td><td>English (Belize) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>en-tt</td><td>English (Trinidad) </td><td>et</td><td>Estonian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>fo</td><td>Faeroese </td><td>fa</td><td>Farsi </td></tr>
    <tr><td>fi</td><td>Finnish </td><td>fr</td><td>French (Standard) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>fr-be</td><td>French (Belgium) </td><td>fr-ca</td><td>French (Canada) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>fr-ch</td><td>French (Switzerland) </td><td>fr-lu</td><td>French (Luxembourg) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>gd</td><td>Gaelic (Scotland) </td><td>ga</td><td>Irish </td></tr>
    <tr><td>de</td><td>German (Standard) </td><td>de-ch</td><td>German (Switzerland) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>de-at</td><td>German (Austria) </td><td>de-lu</td><td>German (Luxembourg) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>de-li</td><td>German (Liechtenstein) </td><td>el</td><td>Greek </td></tr>
    <tr><td>he</td><td>Hebrew </td><td>hi</td><td>Hindi </td></tr>
    <tr><td>hu</td><td>Hungarian </td><td>is</td><td>Icelandic </td></tr>

    <tr><td>id</td><td>Indonesian </td><td>it</td><td>Italian (Standard) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>it-ch</td><td>Italian (Switzerland) </td><td>ja</td><td>Japanese </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ko</td><td>Korean </td><td>ko</td><td>Korean (Johab) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>lv</td><td>Latvian </td><td>lt</td><td>Lithuanian </td></tr>

    <tr><td>mk</td><td>Macedonian (FYROM)</td><td>ms</td><td>Malaysian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>mt</td><td>Maltese </td><td>no</td><td>Norwegian (Bokmal) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>no</td><td>Norwegian (Nynorsk) </td><td>pl</td><td>Polish </td></tr>
    <tr><td>pt-br</td><td>Portuguese (Brazil) </td><td>pt</td><td>Portuguese (Portugal) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>rm</td><td>Rhaeto-Romanic </td><td>ro</td><td>Romanian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ro-mo</td><td>Romanian (Republic of Moldova) </td><td>ru</td><td>Russian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ru-mo</td><td>Russian (Republic of Moldova) </td><td>sz</td><td>Sami (Lappish) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>sr</td><td>Serbian (Cyrillic) </td><td>sr</td><td>Serbian (Latin) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>sk</td><td>Slovak </td><td>sl</td><td>Slovenian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>sb</td><td>Sorbian </td><td>es</td><td>Spanish (Spain) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-mx</td><td>Spanish (Mexico) </td><td>es-gt</td><td>Spanish (Guatemala) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-cr</td><td>Spanish (Costa Rica) </td><td>es-pa</td><td>Spanish (Panama) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>es-do</td><td>Spanish (Dominican Republic) </td><td>es-ve</td><td>Spanish (Venezuela) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-co</td><td>Spanish (Colombia) </td><td>es-pe</td><td>Spanish (Peru) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-ar</td><td>Spanish (Argentina) </td><td>es-ec</td><td>Spanish (Ecuador) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-cl</td><td>Spanish (Chile) </td><td>es-uy</td><td>Spanish (Uruguay) </td></tr>

    <tr><td>es-py</td><td>Spanish (Paraguay) </td><td>es-bo</td><td>Spanish (Bolivia) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-sv</td><td>Spanish (El Salvador) </td><td>es-hn</td><td>Spanish (Honduras) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>es-ni</td><td>Spanish (Nicaragua) </td><td>es-pr</td><td>Spanish (Puerto Rico) </td></tr>
    <tr><td>sx</td><td>Sutu </td><td>sv</td><td>Swedish </td></tr>

    <tr><td>sv-fi</td><td>Swedish (Finland) </td><td>th</td><td>Thai </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ts</td><td>Tsonga </td><td>tn</td><td>Tswana </td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr</td><td>Turkish </td><td>uk</td><td>Ukrainian </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ur</td><td>Urdu </td><td>ve</td><td>Venda </td></tr>

    <tr><td>vi</td><td>Vietnamese </td><td>xh</td><td>Xhosa </td></tr>
    <tr><td>ji</td><td>Yiddish </td><td>zu</td><td>Zulu </td></tr>
    ';
    error_reporting(E_PARSE | E_ERROR);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($strLcodes);

    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $path = $xml->xpath('//td');
    echo "<pre>";
    $strpath  = implode('|',$path);

    echo str_replace(' |', '<br/>',$strpath);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Comment: Hi @simple, thanks for that. But how would go about converting the codes like en_US to "English" with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more choice (e.g. the name of the languages for display in other languages and so on and so forth), take a look into the *Common Language Data Repository (CLDR)* by the Unicode Consortium.

```
http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main
```

You will find easily parseable XML files that contain information about those codes (and other stuff) collected by many individuals all over the planet with the aim to make this more accessible.

You can easily checkout the directories out from there with `svn`, use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and then `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to aquire the information.

Answer (score 0):

You may use php_intl (=international) extension, which is an official extension (but might not be on by default, if so, extension=php_intl.so is needed in php.ini).

```
<?php

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.2', '<=')) {
    exit ('php_intl extension is available on PHP 5.3.2 or later.');
}    
if (!class_exists('Locale')) {
    exit ('You need to install php_intl extension.');
}

$locales = [ 'en_US', 'de_DE', 'en_GB', 'it_IT', 'fr_FR' ];
$localeToDisplay = 'en_US';

foreach ($locales as $locale) {
    echo $locale . ": " . Locale::getDisplayLanguage($locale, $localeToDisplay) . PHP_EOL;
}
/* output
en_US: English
de_DE: German
en_GB: English
it_IT: Italian
fr_FR: French
*/
```